# Is it true that the same player scored four goals in the match between Liverpool and Chester City in 1968 which ended 2-2?

Tags: football, trivia

I found a book about trivia and there is the following passage (in Indonesian):

[image]

> Did you know that in a match between Liverpool and Chester City in 1968, which ended with a score of 2-2, there was something very strange and unique?
> Yes, the four goals were created by the very same person.

I found this unique but when I tried to search about this match on Wikipedia, I couldn't find anything, either in [1967-68 Liverpool F.C. season](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1967%E2%80%9368_Liverpool_F.C._season), [1968-69 Liverpool F.C. season](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1968%E2%80%9369_Liverpool_F.C._season), [1967-68 Chester F.C. season](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1967%E2%80%9368_Chester_F.C._season), or [1968-69 Chester F.C. season](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1968%E2%80%9369_Chester_F.C._season). The fact that the author of this book did not mention the competition in which this match took place makes it difficult to verify.

So my question is, did this match really happen? If so, who is the name of the player who scored all the goals in that match?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, this is not true. However, a different game actually did have this strange record.

Liverpool and Chester only played draw once, a 1-1 in 1940.

The record in question actually happened in 1976, when [Leicester - Aston Villa](https://www.worldfootball.net/report/premier-league-1975-1976-leicester-city-aston-villa/) ended 2-2 with all goals scored by Chris Nicholl.

Comment: Did that Liverpool and Chester game in 1940 take place in the First Division?

Comment: @alif the 1940 season was part of the Wartime league, replacing the suspended English football leagues during World War II

Comment: Wow that is crazy! According to that link,  he scored both goals for his team and own goals in quick succession,  each at the end of each half!  Were any enquiries made into his gambling activity?